# --watch arg is unsupported on Windows

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I'm new to jekyll so first I follow this tutorial  [Jekyll on Windows](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/windows/#installation) and setup jekyll 3.3.0.I got an error about the certificate this tutorial [SSL CERTIFICATE UPDATES](http://guides.rubygems.org/ssl-certificate-update/)
 and by using this [cacert.pem](https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem) certificate solve the problem.
However,when start jekyll server I get:

> --watch arg is unsupported on Windows.
>                       If you are on Windows Bash, please see: https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/216

I try to solve this problem using [Let Jekyll --watch](http://jekyll-windows.juthilo.com/4-wdm-gem/) without any luck.
If I use jekyll 3.2.1 every things work okay but the problem with jekyll 3.3.0.
So how to solve this problem ?

[image: jekyll 3.3.0 error on windows]

## Edit

I Solve my problem reading [this](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/5462#issuecomment-253483146) and comment some code in the `build.rb` file at `C:\tools\ruby23\lib\ruby\gems\2.3.0\gems\jekyll-3.3.0\lib\jekyll\commands` 
To enable autoregeration and now every things work okay.

```
def watch(site, options)
          #if Utils::Platforms.windows?
          #  Jekyll.logger.warn "", "--watch arg is unsupported on Windows. "
          #  Jekyll.logger.warn "", "If you are on Windows Bash, please see: " \
          #     "https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/216"

         # else
            External.require_with_graceful_fail "jekyll-watch"
            watch_method = Jekyll::Watcher.method(:watch)
            if watch_method.parameters.size == 1
              watch_method.call(
                options
              )
            else
              watch_method.call(
                options, site
              )
           # end
          end
```

Comment: Reading that link as suggested says that the issue is fixed in a preview build of Windows. I'd just keep using 3.2.1 until Windows releases the fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by installing [Ruby 2.3.3](https://dl.bintray.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/rubyinstaller-2.3.3-x64.exe), [DevKit-mingw64](https://dl.bintray.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/DevKit-mingw64-64-4.7.2-20130224-1432-sfx.exe) and jekyll 3.4.3

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just type `jekyll serve`.

Comment: I got this error when type jekyll server and site is working but watch not working

Comment: It's not about jekyll only, for all gems the `--watch` command in windows is unsupported. `jekyll server` is by default run `jekyll server --watch`

Answer (score 0):

It's windows bash error, Jekyll or Windows will fix it soon, till then you can use jekyll 3.2.1 version.

[Here I commit my answer.](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/5462#issuecomment-253483146)